# How to remove H1 tag from joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, web, web-development-server

I have tried a lot to remove H1 Tag from my website based on joomla 2.5.. Everything i tried to do, but nothing was useful to me. click on [website](https://www.purpleno.in) url for details

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Ideally for SEO purposes your web page should have exactly one H1 heading.

It looks like the current H1 heading is associated with the slider extension. If there's no option to switch it off in the slider settings, you could create [a custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/3877/120) and hide it using CSS like this or similar:

```
.djslider h1 {display: none;}
```